# Change chart marker color if there is continuous value higher than a baseline value

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently creating a VBA macro to change the color of the marker of a chart if the value in the chart consists of 3 continuous spikes that exceeds a baseline value of 0.7.

For example, in the picture below, I've create a macro to change all the marker colors to red if the value is higher than the baseline value, but not if there are 3 continuous values higher than baseline value.
[image: Example Chart]

**My Code**

This is what I've tried - changing the marker color to red if the value exceeds 0.7

```
Sub Tester()

Dim cht As Chart, s As Series, p As point
Dim vals, x As Integer

    Set cht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("mySheet3").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart
    Set s = cht.SeriesCollection(1)
    vals = s.Values
    
    For x = LBound(vals) To UBound(vals)
      If vals(x) > 0.7 Then
        With s.Points(x)
            .MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            .MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End With
      End If
    Next x
    
End Sub
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code? What is the question?

Comment: I want the code to be able to change the marker color when there is only 3 consecutive value that is higher than the baseline value , not each of them that are higher than the baseline value. Do you get what i meant ? @Pᴇʜ

Comment: If there is more than 3 consecutives like 5 you want all 5 red or only the first 3?

Comment: all 5 @Pᴇʜ is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you would need to work with a window size to check always 3 dots in a row if they are above basline if the are color them and move 1 further to check the next 3 in a row.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Tester()
    Dim cht As Chart
    Set cht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("mySheet3").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart
    
    Dim s As Series
    Set s = cht.SeriesCollection(1)
    
    Dim vals As Variant
    vals = s.Values
    
    Const WindowSize As Long = 3
    Dim Colorize As Boolean
    
    Dim x As Long
    For x = LBound(vals) To UBound(vals)
        If x + WindowSize - 1 <= UBound(vals) Then
            Colorize = True
            Dim w As Long
            For w = x To x + WindowSize - 1
                If Not vals(w) > 0.7 Then
                    Colorize = False
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next w
            If Colorize Then
                For w = x To x + WindowSize - 1
                    With s.Points(w)
                        .MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                        .MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    End With
                Next w
             End If
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Omg , i am so grateful that you've helped me solve all the questions regarding VBA . Thank you so much for your help !

Comment: @SteveKush I put a `Exit For` right after `Colorize = False` that makes it a bit faster.

Comment: Alright , will do Sir. Thank you so much.